# Run application after install if box checked

Tags: wix

I am using Wix toolset from commandline (first time, quite a steep curve) and have the installer working correctly but I want the app to start if the user checks a box on the last page. Here's what I have so far:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
        xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui"
        >
        <Package Manufacturer="$ (var.publisher)" Name="$(var.name)" Scope="perMachine" UpgradeCode="$(var.guid)" Version="$(var.version)">
                <Media Cabinet="setup.cab" EmbedCab="yes" Id="1"/>
                <Feature Id="InstallFeature" Title="Install Feature">
                        <ComponentRef Id="file"/>
                        <ComponentRef Id="config.json"/>
                        <ComponentRef Id="conn.json"/>
                        <ComponentRef Id="user.json"/>
                        <ComponentRef Id="sheet.txt"/>
                </Feature>
                <StandardDirectory Id="PersonalFolder">
                        <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="myApp">
                                <Component DiskId="1" Id="file">
                                        <File Id="executable" Name="$(var.exe)" Source="$(var.path)\$(var.exe)"/>
                                </Component>
                                <Component DiskId="1" Id="config.json">
                                        <File Id="config.json" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.path)\config.json"/>
                                </Component>
                                <Component DiskId="1" Id="conn.json">
                                        <File Id="conn.json" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.path)\conn.json"/>
                                </Component>
                                <Component DiskId="1" Id="user.json">
                                        <File Id="user.json" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.path)\user.json"/>
                                </Component>
                                <Directory Id="SubFolder" Name="sheets">
                                        <Component DiskId="1" Id="sheet.txt">
                                                <File Id="sheet.txt" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.path)\sheet.txt"/>
                                        </Component>
                                </Directory>
                        </Directory>
                </StandardDirectory>
                <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="license.rtf" />
                <Property
                  Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT"
                  Value="Launch myApp"
                  />
                <CustomAction Id="run_exe" Return="asyncWait" Execute="commit"
                        ExeCommand="$(var.silentArgs)" HideTarget="yes" Impersonate="no"
                        FileRef="executable" />

                <InstallExecuteSequence>
                        <Custom Action="run_exe" After="InstallFinalize"
                                Condition="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1" />
                </InstallExecuteSequence>


        <ui:WixUI
                Id="WixUI_InstallDir"
                InstallDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION"
                />
        </Package>
</Wix>
```

The wxs builds fine into an MSI and I can run the installer successfully. However, I expect the exe to run based on InstallExecuteSequence calling the CustomAction run_exe. After the installer runs, the application is installed but does not start up. I have messed the with the condition a variety of ways without success.